# Is there an alternative for Postgres for Python 3.9?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, python-3.9

I am trying to use `psycopg2` to connect to a Postgres DB but apparently it is not supported in 3.9. Is there another alternative I can use?

Comment: There is also https://www.psycopg.org/articles/2021/10/13/psycopg-30-released/ version 3 that has just been released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation says that 3.9 is supported

> Python versions from 3.6 to 3.9

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#prerequisites

Here is list on Postgres Wiki for other libs https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python

You can also search on python package index https://pypi.org/search/?q=postgre&o=&c=Topic+%3A%3A+Database&c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+Python

Comment: That's weird. I've been trying to install it but it gives an error and everywhere I've searched it says it's unsupported. I wonder why. Anyway, thank you for the info. I'll accept the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I first tried installing it through the UI in Pycharm but it gave the error. After that I ran the command `pip install psycopg2` in the terminal and it outputs a bunch of errors and the last one says `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2 (from versions: *a bunch of versions here that end in 2.9.1*)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2`

Comment: @plasmy `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: @plasmy see https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#psycopg-vs-psycopg-binary and https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#psycopg-vs-psycopg-binary

Comment: I tried the binary command and it installed. Does it work the same way as psycopg2? I've never used the library before so I'm assuming I can use the same functions and classes?

Comment: @plasmy read link above